# Criteria for passing SafetyNet Verify Apps API

Tags: android, safetynet

I created an app that uses the `SafetyNet Verify Apps` API. The app is working without any error and in all the devices that I tested it, it said no harmful apps were found. I would like to know if what are the criteria for an app to pass the `SafetyNet` test. If I know that I will create an app that will fail the test to verify if the feature is working correctly. I tried to read through Google's documentation but I was unable to find anything in this matter.

Is there such an app? What feature must my app have to fail the `SafetyNet` test?

Comment: Apps don't fail safetynet.  Devices might.

Comment: @GabeSechan Apps will fail SafetyNet Verify Apps feature. https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/verify-apps.html This API returns the list of harmful apps installed in your device.

Answer (score 0):

An app will fail the check if it is determined by Google to be "malicious".

Think of Verify Apps as something similar to an antivirus. It will catch what the developers define as a malicious app. The definition is opaque, and might change from app to app.

So if you want to see Verify Apps catching something, how about you get a test device with nothing important in it, or emulator, and then try finding some malware and install it into the device? Doing this may in the worst case, damage your device, so do it at your own risk.